# Does UIImageView have a property to indicate setImage has completed and animations are ready?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimageview

Just getting started with Obj-C and iOS programming.  I have some code that loads and imageView into a (HIDDEN: YES) UIView - simply

```
[bgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Filename.jpg"];
```

The code then sets and commits animations on the fgImageView and the bgImageView.
Because some of the images can be large, occasionally the animation from the new bgImage does not render with the new background image in it and instead 'stalls and displays'.  Note that the stall does not happen during setImage.  It happens during the second animationCommit later in code.  Because animationCommit forces the application to wait until the animation of this ImageView is done.

What I'm looking for is sort of a 'setImage commit' on UIImageView,

I'd much rather display a spinner until the image is loaded, then proceed with the animation, however there doesn't appear to be an isLoaded property for UIImageView class.

Is there a simple way to determine that the UIImageView is done with the setImage call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in UIImageView `- (BOOL)isAnimating`, so you could potentially use:

```
if (![bgImageView isAnimating]) {
    // continue to next image;
}
```

Would that suffice or is there other animation in progress that would give false responses?

Comment: I have tried this, to no avail - isAnimating apparently does not identify that the uiimageview is still busy scaling the image in the background.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  It's a bit messier, but it's possible to override the `setImage:` method with `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image { [super setImage:image]; // your custom code; }`.  Worse comes to worst, you could include a notification in there to be sent to the main thread that lets it know it can continue to the next image

Comment: And I could indeed do that, if I had any way to tell when the image was done scaling/loading - but that problem remains.  I appreciate the help - but the //your custom code block is still the question - how do I know the image is indeed ready to animate?

Comment: After looking around with just about every possible search field for a solution for you, I cannot find an answer to find when an image has indeed scaled and loaded.  However, I did find a link that could prove useful if this fits your situation, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624279/iphone-knowing-when-an-uiimageview-has-loaded-its-image).  Basically it says that a UIImageView is not meant to hold large images and provides ways to resize them to avoid problems (without destroying the quality of the original).  If this is not the case, though, I will continue to look around

Comment: Thanks for the effort, slev - I will take to heart this suggestion and instead of just using UIImage imageNamed directly into the view, I'll resize an image according to [link] (http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) referenced by your post here.  That way the UIImageView won't be dealing with the crazy big file itself, but a properly scaled version, when its time to animate it.

Answer (score 1):

My gut is that setImage is handled synchronously, especially since you're talking about how the app stalls.  You'd want to run setImage in an NSOperation to allow that happen in the background.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSInvocationOperation *myOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:myImageView selector@selector(setImage:) object:aUIImage];
[myOp addObserver:(NSObject *)self forKeyPath:(NSString *) @"isFinished" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
[anOpQueue addOperation:myOp];
```

You'd then handle the KVO operation and handle removing the spinner there.

Comment: The application does not stall - the animationcommit on bgimage does stall - but the code between setimage and that animationcommit runs (e.g. the fgimage animation completes and then it stalls, that's 7 lines of code later)

Comment: In fact, were it to stall, that would be better - setImage appears to be loading and scaling the image in a background thread.  I am trying to identify that the background thread has completed and uiimageview is ready for animation.

Comment: More to the point - it appears setImage loads synchronously, but UIImageView scales the image asynchronously.....therein lies the crux, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`[UIImageView setImage:]` is not asynchronous: It's done immediately before the message returns. If the view does not show the image instantly it's probably because of some lazy UIImage code. My guess is that `[UIImage imageNamed:]` just references the file in the bundle and loads it only after the image data is requested.

You could try to force the image to load by sending it a CGImage message:

```
[bgImageView.image CGImage];
```

If this still does not trigger the image to be loaded you have to draw it somewhere:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((CGSize){1, 1});
[bgImageView drawInRect:(CGRect){{0, 0}, {1, 1}}];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: bgImageView does not respond to drawInRect, but bgImageView.image does.  Unfortunately, neither code block seems to force a synchronous wait for the image to truly be ready/scaled/loaded.

Comment: While the image may be loaded - it is probably not finished scaling - the image is 1.5MB in size.